# How to install new drupal packages on local apache server

Tags: installation

I have a drupal site set up on a local mysql and a local apache server. I am trying to install a new module the problem is it brings me to the login for server ftp. I'm not sure what credentials it wants or how to do it exactly is there some way to enable apache ftp or what am I supppsed to be doing.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a permission issue. You might want to make `sites` directory owned by the apache user and the themes or modules folder is writable as well.

```
$ chown -R www-data sites # Change owner sites directory
```

If that doesn't work, you might try setting modules and theme dir writable.

```
$ chmod -R 777 sites/all
```

Ref: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2011-01-22/module-installation-requires-ftp-access